# What to Deploy for Windows Services?

Tags: deployment, windows-services

Is all we need to copy across is .exe and .exe.config ?

or do we need to copy .dll's and .xml as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any 3rd party dll (or any dll which is not a part of the .NET Framework) being used by your service then you will need to copy it along with your executable. Hope you also know that .NET framework must be installed in the target machine where you are planning to deploy your service.